# SimGrid. Create subprocess with argument

Tags: c, simgrid

I have process declared in `main.c`:

```
MSG_function_register("dispatcher", dispatcher);
```

The `dispatcher` function gets arguments from `deployment.xml` file:

```
int num = xbt_str_parse_int(argv[1], "Invalid argument %s");
int id = xbt_str_parse_int(argv[2], "Invalid argument %s");
```

Then `dispatcher` creates a subprocess:

```
MSG_process_create_with_arguments("TS", subprocess, NULL, MSG_host_self(), agrc, argv);
```

How can I pass `num` and `id` to subprocess function?

```
int subprocess(int argc, char* argv){
    return 0;
}
```

How can I call this argv inside from subprocess function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 ways to pass arguments to MSG processes:

- either via the argv;
- or via the `data` argument.

### Pass the data via `argv`

In the first solution, you have to create a new `argv`:

```
// Create argv for child process
char** newargv = xbt_new(char*, 3);
newargv[1] = xbt_strdup("TS");
newargv[2] = xbt_strdup(argv[0]);
newargv[3] = xbt_strdup(argv[0]);
// Create process with new argv:
MSG_process_create_with_arguments("TS", subprocess, NULL,     MSG_host_self(), 3, newargv);
```

with:

```
int subprocess(int argc, char* argv)
{
    int num = xbt_str_parse_int(argv[1], "Invalid argument %s");
    int id = xbt_str_parse_int(argv[2], "Invalid argument %s");
    return 0;
}
```

### Pass the data via `data`

Another solution is to pass the data using the `data` parameter:

```
struct ts_data {
  int num;
  int id;
};

struct ts_data* data = xbt_new(ts_data, 1);
data->num = xbt_str_parse_int(argv[1], "Invalid argument %s");
data->id = xbt_str_parse_int(argv[2], "Invalid argument %s");
MSG_process_create_with_arguments("TS", subprocess, data,     MSG_host_self(), 0, NULL
```

with:

```
int subprocess(int argc, char* argv)
{
    struct ts_data* data = MSG_process_get_data(MSG_process_self());
    int num = data->num;
    int id = data->id;
    free(data);
    return 0;
}
```